# Threejs geometry vertices order

Tags: three.js

wondering if I a just don‘t see it in the docs, but how do I know which vertex belongs to which corner of my geometry (e.g. BoxGeometry)?
Is there any documentation telling this in general?
Thanks, fwerre

Comment: `THREE.BoxGeometry()` has an array of [`THREE.Face3()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Face3), each face has `a`, `b`, `c` properties that contains indices of vertices from `.vertices` array.

Comment: as far as I know there is nothing documented about this, you will need to refer to the implementation (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/geometries) if you want to go into these details.

Answer (score 1):

Isn‘t this a general interest, to be able to address certain vertices (and to know where they are)?